FATFS via SPI for NUCLEOF103RB not working, returns FR_NOT_READY (3)
I have been sitting on this problem for a couple of days where I have been trying to use f_mount on a 8GB SD card (I formatted it to FAT32 and to a sector size of 4096.) I am also copying a very popular library by eziya: https://blog.naver.com/eziya76/221188701172. The chip I am using on my NUCLEO board is a STM32F103RB.
Although the program is very simple, no matter what I do, the SD card never gets mounted. When trying to read the available space and the total space, it always returns 0.
Here is my code for the main loop:
FATFS fs;
FIL fil;
FRESULT fresult;
char buffer[1024];

UINT br, bw;

FATFS *pfs;
DWORD fre_clust;
uint32_t total, free_space;

fresult = f_mount(&fs, "", 1);
printf("%d \n", fresult);
if (fresult != FR_OK) printf("Unsuccessful again\n");
else printf("Mounted successfully! \n");

f_getfree("", &fre_clust, &pfs);
total = (uint32_t)((pfs->n_fatent - 2) * pfs->csize * 0.5);
printf("Total size: \t%lu\n",total);
free_space = (uint32_t)(fre_clust * pfs->csize * 0.5);
printf("SD CARD free space: \t%lu\n", free_space);

I used SPI for the configuration, here are my configurations for the CubeIDE:
SPI configuration:

FATFS configuration:

SPI pinout in the CubeIDE:

I set the CS output on default high for the SPI communication protocol.

The clock configuration:

I use this SD card reader module

What I have tried and didn't work:

Switch out the SD card reader module.

Switch out the microSD card.

Use an internal Pull-up resistor for the MOSI and CS lines (I didn't have an option to choose pull-up resistors. for MISO and SCK.)

Have "Low" as default CS output.

Checked the SCK signal on the oscilloscope and it was reading something, which seemed to me alright, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

Put some signs into the "" of the f_mount input.

Use 0 as the initialization input for the f_mount function (this returns always FR_OK though, so it doesn't really help.)

Double check SPI connections (everything should be connected correctly.)


Any help is welcome, thank you so much!

Use the debugger to step into the f_mount function to discover exactly why it is failing to narrow down the problem.  What does "Have "Low" as default CS output." mean?

@Clifford „Low“ as CS output means is that the default output level is low and in order to select the IC, the line has to be pulled up. However, since it is nCS, and the person whose library I am using say otherwise, this should not work. And how can I narrow the problem exactly down? Can I look at specific functions?

Most of the FatFs functions can return a failure for multiple reasons.  By stepping through and into the call stack you will discover exactly what condition the function is failing on.  That will narrow down the gamut of possible causes.  Right now you are trying a whole set of random and implausible solutions with no viable hypothesis that in some cases will actually cause failure but for different reasons.  You should revert all those attempts and approach this in a more methodical manner.  You know; like you would debug any code - even if in fact it is a hardware issue.

Note that eziya's code is an example port of http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/.  eziya is not the author of the FatFs library itself.  In fact the FatFs library is already an integral part of the STM32Cube SDK that is already included with STM32CubeIDE and CubeMX.  All the necessary code and configuration  can be generated in the the IDE without additional third party code.

You have added code to print the return value from f_mount but failed to report what that result is.  That is important diagnostic information (although better to read it in a debugger than to require or expect printf to work as well).  f_mount can return any of: FR_OK, FR_INVALID_DRIVE, FR_DISK_ERR, FR_NOT_READY, FR_NOT_ENABLED, FR_NO_FILESYSTEM.  With that knowledge you can simply place a breakpoint at any point in the function that that value is returned to catch precisely where it is failing and why.

@Clifford In the title I specified the error, it is FR_NOT_READY, I read that through the debugger. But could you elaborate more on placing a breakpoint, you mean I should place a breakpoint in the f_mount function declaration?
Also, I thought that was eziya wrote is a driver which I need in order to use the SD card?

@Clifford so I have followed your advice with the break points and figured out two errors, the first one is: FR_NOT_READY and FR_DISK_ERR. The errors happen inside the find_volume function and inside there, the error is happening like this:
fs->fs_type = 0;     /* Clear the file system object */   fs->drv = LD2PD(vol);    /* Bind the logical drive and a physical drive */   stat = disk_initialize(fs->drv); /* Initialize the physical drive */   if (stat & STA_NOINIT) { /* Check if the initialization succeeded */   return FR_NOT_READY; }

And there:
#if _MAX_SS != _MIN_SS  /* Get sector size (multiple sector size cfg only) */  if (disk_ioctl(fs->drv, GET_SECTOR_SIZE, &SS(fs)) != RES_OK   || SS(fs) < _MIN_SS || SS(fs) > _MAX_SS) {   return FR_DISK_ERR; 

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You need to update the question with the debug information or figure it out yourself, or post a new question.  Comments are not the place to post code or ask run on questions.  So is not a char forum, it is a Q&A.  Your question is unanswerable as it stands (ignoring the comments).

SO is not a discussion forum (dumb auto-correct)

So in the end I was able to figure out the issue. I did what was suggested and went through the program step-by-step through breakpoints. What I found is that is was definitely a hardware issue. I switched out a bunch of these blue SD card reader modules, and it still didn't work. However, when I used a totally different SD card reader from SparkFun, it suddenly worked. NONE of these blue SD card reader modules worked. To sum it up -- Beware of these Blue Devils.

The question of why they did not work is best addressed at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.  You don't specify a part number or supplier, so "avoiding" them may be difficult - being "blue" is not much if an identification.  My advice would be to never buy any board for which no schematic or user manual or electrical specification is provided or available before purchase.  Possibly it is designed for 5V logic and your STM32 is 3.3V.

Looking around at similar boards it seems at least that the supply must be 5V, but 3.3V or 5V logic is supported.
